# How check if specific record exist in table or not

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which I have multiple dates stored which are the attendance dates of employee

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance
(
EmpCode INT,
AttendanceDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-01');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-02');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-03');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-04');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-06');
```

Now as there is not date saved for this employee on 5th Dec it should show Absent in that case.

```
SELECT * FROM Attendance
```

Comment: Where is the list of dates to check against?

Comment: you'd need a CTE or a calendar lookup table and you may want to consider dealing with weekends and holidays... as it stands there's not enough information to provide a complete answer.

Comment: @Tanner I already have handled all that stuff but I am unable to create a logic that how to check against a date that does not exist in table.

Comment: I can check which date is Holiday and Weekend and all stuff but if employee haven't marked any attendance any day which means there won't be any data to check against. In that case I want to display `A` or `Absent` in that row

Comment: so what about other scenarios?  What if he had not turned up on  2018-12-01?  Would that be an absence?  And if so, how do you know that?

Comment: What if December 5 was a holiday and he should have been "absent"?

Answer (score 1):

It will give missed date for that emp from table if you want to insert you can insert by using existing code

```
CREATE TABLE #Attendance
(
EmpCode INT,
AttendanceDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-01');
INSERT INTO #Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-02');
INSERT INTO #Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-03');
INSERT INTO #Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-04');
INSERT INTO #Attendance VALUES (24, '2018-12-06');

select * from #Attendance

 ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'2018-12-01') AS DATE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,DATE1) FROM CTE WHERE DATE1<'2018-12-06'
    )
    --insert into #Attendance(EmpCode,AttendanceDate)
    SELECT DATE1 MISSING_ONE,'a' FROM CTE
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT AttendanceDate,'a' FROM #Attendance
    option(maxrecursion 0)
```